# Adding python script to c++ project

Tags: c++, python, visual-studio, boost-python

How would I go about adding a script written in python to a c++ project? Thanks

Edit: Basically all the script does is email some data. I would like to pass the data and maybe the email address to a function written in python. Hope that clears things up..

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific. Does the C++ program need to run the script? Get variables back from the script? Or are you just trying to translate it to c++?

Answer (score 3):

You could look at [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/python/doc/index.html) which is a "a C++ library which enables seamless interoperability between C++ and the Python programming language."

You have to be more specific, though.

Answer (score 3):

You may be interested in [Boost.Python: Embedding the Interpreter](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/embedding.html), or [Python/C API: Embedding the Python Interpreter](http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html). You can either use the Python C APIs directly or use the Boost.Python library as you so choose. You might also be interested in reading [Embedding Python in Your C Programs](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8497) which walks you through it.

Answer (score 1):

The most primitve solution would be to use the system command to call you script, but that does limit your control over it to setting environment variables and passing parameters.

```
system("myscript.py param1 param2")
```